# android convert rtsp to MP4 ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, rtsp

1.Gradle

```
dependencies { api 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.5' }
```

2.Code

```
String[] ffmpegCommand = new String[]{"-rtsp_transport","tcp", "-i", rtspUrl,"-g","100", "-f", "mp4", "-r", "20", "-s", "640x480", filePath};
    return ffmpeg.execute(ffmpegCommand, new FFcommandExecuteResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String s) {
            LogUtil.d(Rtsp2FilePresenter.class.getName(), "startRecord onSuccess :" + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(String s) {
            LogUtil.d(Rtsp2FilePresenter.class.getName(), "startRecord onProgress :" + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String s) {
            LogUtil.d(Rtsp2FilePresenter.class.getName(), "startRecord onFailure :" + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            LogUtil.d(Rtsp2FilePresenter.class.getName(), "startRecord onStart :");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            LogUtil.d(Rtsp2FilePresenter.class.getName(), "startRecord onFinish :");
        }
    });
```

3.Logcat:

> built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)
> configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-ffprobe --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-yasm --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-linux-perf --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-nonfree --enable-network --enable-avresample --enable-avformat --enable-avcodec --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-small --enable-nonfree --pkg-config=pkg-config --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags=
> libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
> libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
> libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
> libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
> libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
> libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
> libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
> libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
> libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0xee6c9380] no frame!

question :how to fix the command ?? but the command can run on windows without error......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> String[] ffmpegCommand = new String[]{"-rtsp_transport","udp", "-i",
> rtspUrl,"-g","100", "-f", "mp4", "-r", "20", "-s", "640x480",
> filePath};

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).